# How to use regexp to find unique combinations of letters and use them as variables in Matlab?

Tags: regex, matlab, cells

I have the file names of four files stored in a cell array called F2000.  These files are named:

- L14N_2009_2000MHZ.txt
- L8N_2009_2000MHZ.txt
- L14N_2010_2000MHZ.txt
- L8N_2009_2000MHZ.txt

Each file consists of an mxn matrix where m is the same but n varies from file to file.  I'd like to store each of the L14N files and each of the L8N files in two separate cell arrays so I can use dlmread in a for loop to store each text file as a matrix in an element of the cell array.  To do this, I wrote the following code:

```
idx2009=cellfun('isempty',regexp(F2000,'L\d{1,2}N_2009_2000MHZ.txt'));
F2000_2009=F2000(idx2009);
idx2010=~idx2009;
F2000_2010=F2000(idx2010);
cell2009=cell(size(F2000_2009));
cell2010=cell(size(F2000_2010));
for k = 1:numel(F2000_2009)
  cell2009{k}=dlmread(F2000_2009{k});
end
```

and repeated a similar "for" loop to use on F2000_2010.  So far so good.  However.

My real data set is much larger than just four files.  The total number of files will vary, although I know there will be five years of data for each L\d{1,2}N (so, for instance, L8N_2009, L8N_2010, L8N_2011, L8N_2012, L8N_2013).  I won't know what the number of files is ahead of time (although I do know it will range between 50 and 100), and I won't know what the file names are, but they will always be in the same L\d{1,2}N format.

In addition to what's already working, I want to count the number of files that have unique combinations of numbers in the portion of the filename that says L\d{1,2}N so I can further break down F2000_2010 and F2000_2009 in the above example to F2000_2010_L8N and F2000_2009_L8N before I start the dlmread loop.

Can I use regexp to build a list of all of my unique L\d{1,2}N occurrences?  Next, can I easily change these list elements to strings to parse the original file names and create a new file name to the effect of L14N_2009, where 14 comes from \d{1,2}?  I am sure this is a beginner question, but I discovered regexp yesterday!  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Matlab have hashes or associative array's? Loop each file on `(L\d{1,2}N)` , store key like `hash['<capture grp1>']`. Sort the array, then loop the files on each key, `<key>(.*)`. Don't know Matlab's capabilities.

Comment: Great question..I did not find anything on Matlab supporting hashes and associative arrays, but if anyone has details or (better yet!) examples (as I am new, painfully new, at most of this) I would be very interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code which might help:

% Find all the files in your directory

```
files = dir('*2000MHZ.txt');
files = {files.name};
```

% match identifiers

```
 ids = unique(cellfun(@(x)x{1},regexp(files,'L\d{1,2}N','match'),...
              'UniformOutput',false));
```

% find all years

```
years = unique(cellfun(@(x)x{1},regexp(files,'(?<=L\d{1,2}N_)\d{4,}','match'),...
               'UniformOutput',false));
```

% find the years for each identifier

```
for id_ix = 1:length(ids) 
    % There is probably a better way to do this
    list = regexp(files,['(?<=' ids{id_ix} '_)\d{4,}'],'match');
    ids_years{id_ix} = cellfun(@(x)x{1},list(cellfun(...
                               @(x)~isempty(x),list)),'uniformoutput',false);
end
```

% If you ***need*** dynamic naming, I would suggest dynamic struct names:

```
for ix_id = 1:length(ids)
    for ix_year = 1:length(ids_years{ix_id})
        % the 'Y' is in the dynamic name becuase all struct field names must start with a letter
        data.(ids{ix_id}).(['Y' ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year}]) =...
                                         'read in my data here for each one';
    end
end
```

Also, if anyone is interested in mapping keys with values try looking into the containers.map class.

Comment: This is a great solution! But I have a question. I added a for loop on the outside of the dynamic naming: `for jx=1:numel(files)` and, where you have 'read in my data here...', I used dlmread(files{jx}). Understandably, the output is a structure where I have all desired combinations (data.14N.Y2009, data.14N.Y2010, etc) but the value of each is the value obtained for dlmread(files{numel(files)}). For a matrix, I'd store each stage of the for loop using data(jx), but I'm not sure how to do this same type of thing for structures. Sorry for remedial question..this is all very, very new to me.

Comment: In case you're wondering why I can't just work within that loop, the remaining tasks are many and perhaps I am lazy.  I would find it easier to be able to call in the various matrices by name (hence need for dynamic naming) so I can test portions of my code on various combinations (L14N_2009 and L14N_2010, L14N_2009 and L14N_2011) and print presentation-quality plots of the results to independently named files.  I was hoping to construct the filenames for my plots out of the names of the structures to make things simple for me.  If I'm going at this entirely the wrong way, rebukes are welcome.